# Pointer Concept when type casting in C language

Tags: c, pointers

As I'm new to the C language.

```
 void main()
 {
      char *p;
      int a=-22;
      p=(char *)&a;
      *p=0;
      printf("%d",a);

  }
```

When I execute this code I'm getting the output as -256. 
When I print this in %c format I'm getting nothing and when I change *p value to some other thing it is giving some other outputs.

When we execute this what is the output and why?

Comment: Try taking a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: The correct definition for `main` is `int main(void)`, not `void main()`. If you got the idea of `void main()` from a book, its author does not know the language very well; get a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment `*p = 0;` modifies the first byte of `a` (since `p` is a pointer to a `char`, i.e. a pointer to a single-byte value, and `*p` changes only that single-byte value, but `p` points to the beginning of `a`, so `*p` is the first byte of `a`).

Most probably your computer uses little-endian representation of integers and two's complement for negative integers. That's why a 32-bit (4-byte) integer `a` (-22) is represented in memory as `0xEA 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF`. After the `*p = 0;`, `a` looks as `0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF` (notice the change of the first byte), which corresponds to an integer -256

Answer (score 0):

You may try to understand that:-

`%d` is for int specifier

`%c` is for character

`%p` is for pointers

Now in your program the when you are assigning `*p = 0;` then it modifies the first byte of `a` which is why you are getting `-256` as it is represented as `0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF`